# Top bar not functioning properly after upgrade t 23.04

Tags: upgrade

After the upgrade, the (minimize, maximize and close) buttons at top right are not functioning properly. When I click any of them Or the area below them (for eg. while logging off gmail from the My Accout button), Any desk opens up.
I tried uninstalling Anydesk, still the issue remains.
I need Anydesk also , so cannot avoid that .

This video will show the exact issue
https://youtu.be/OarYCzli9cA

Comment: https://youtu.be/OarYCzli9cA

Answer (score 0):

This is a GNome Destop problem. Install XFCE 4 Desktop.